# Finding the index of the smallest element in a 3-dimensional matrix (or n-dimensional)

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a matrix `D(i,j,k)` and I want to find `i`,`j`,`k` so as to minimize `x`:

```
x = D(i,j,k)
```

For example:

```
D = rand(10,10,10);
min(min(min(D))) = 0.5123; %The smallest element in D
```

What I want to know is the index of D that gives 0.5123

How can I do this?
Thanks,
Elliot

Comment: you're question is very unclear. Please clarify your problem by e.g. adding an example. What is a "smallest pair"?

Comment: Ya that part doesn't really matter

Comment: I think it's clear now

Comment: sorry, I didn't know!

Comment: @ElliotG the same for your older question ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [`min`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/min.html) with the `colon` operator, then [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
[xmin,ind] = min(D(:));
[ii,jj,kk] = ind2sub(size(D),ind)
```

Answer (score 5):

The [answer by @chappjc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20911560/2586922) is perfect for the 3D case.

For the ***n*-dimensional** case, use as the output of `ind2sub` a [comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b) obtained from a cell array of size *n*:

```
indices = cell(1,ndims(D)); %// define number of indices (size of cell array)
[minVal linInd] = min(D(:)); %// linear index of minimizer
[indices{:}] = ind2sub(size(D),linInd); %// return indices in cell array
indices = cell2mat(indices); %// convert to nx1 vector containing the indices
```

Comment: Generalization is good. Great example of comma separated list usage with cell arrays.

Comment: @chappjc Thanks for reminding me about the name "comma-separated list". I've edited the answer.

Comment: @chappjc and Luis Mendo, I bow to the elegance of your answers.

Comment: sorry, I gave chappjc the check mark because his answer is better for 3D.

Comment: @ElliotG I agree. You can't beat his answer for the 3D case

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `find` function.

```
D = rand(10,10,10);
[I, J]=find(D == min(min(min(D))));
```

Note that for matrices of more than 2 dimensions:

> If X is an N-dimensional array where N > 2, then J is a linear index over the N-1 trailing
>   dimensions of X

see: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Hope it helps